# Yesterday I exercised so hard that my muscles "are/were" twitching right now - which to use? are or were?

Tags: tense

I did exercises hard yesterday.
Right now, my muscles are twitching.

**Example 1**

> Yesterday I exercised so hard that my muscles **are** twitching right now

**Example 2**

> Yesterday I exercised so hard that my muscles **were** twitching right now

Which example should I use to describe my situation right now?

Does the tense have to conform to the main verb? I feel that Example 2 is more correct.

Comment: You need to use the present progressive "are twitching" if the twitching is still currently occurring.  There is no need to use "right now", since that is what using this tense already means.

Comment: Do you know the difference between past and present generally? Why do you think this situation might be different?

Comment: "Yesterday I exercised so hard that my muscles are still twitching."

Answer (score 6):

If your muscles are twitching when you say this, you use 'are'. If you're trying to say your muscles were twitching yesterday after you exercised, you use 'were', and you don't use 'right now'. English verb tenses generally only apply to the time of the verb itself.